# improper scaling of Qt Desktop application in windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, qtwidgets

I'm writing a simple Qt (Widgets) Gui application for windows 10. I'm using the 5.6.0 beta version of Qt.

The problem I'm having is that it isn't scaling right to the screen of my surfacebook at all:

[image]

It's a bit hard to tell because SO scales the image, but notice how small the dock widget title bar controls are relative to the window title bar controls.

[This link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html) from Qt talks about scaling, but it's mostly focuses on qml/qtQuick and mobile applications in general, and additionally seems to imply that in a desktop QtWidgets application, `QPainter` will automatically determine the proper scaling, which it clearly is not.

What's the best way to ensure that desktop, non-qml Qt applications scale properly on high-DPI monitors, specifically with windows 10?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Qt has recently released a blog post about this issue [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/26/high-dpi-support-in-qt-5-6/).

High DPI support is enabled from Qt 5.6 onward. On OS X platforms, there is native support for High-DPI. On X11/Windows/Android, there are two methods to enable high-DPI detection per the blog post:

1. Set an environment variable
2. Setting an attribute in the program source code

Setting `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1` in your system environment variables will fix the scaling issue.

Additionally, setting `QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` in your application source code should also allow automatic high-DPI scaling.

*NOTICE*: To use the attribute method, you *must* set the attribute *before* you create your `QApplication` object, that is to say:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);   
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I have issues on a multi-monitor setup, and for me, QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 produces correct results... thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you, I had issues with Cura not scaling properly on Win10, this fixed the issue (with rmeoving any previous QT scaling parameters already present)